# Como crear urls tipo twitter (https://twitter.com/@USUARIO)

Tags: .htaccess

me gustaria crear urls tipo twitter (https://twitter.com/@USUARIO) y transmitir el usuario a una variable. ¿Como se podria hacer?

Un saludo

Tengo este codigo, el problema es que quiero que sea @ osea https://ejemplo.com/@usuario. No se como hacerlo

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$  /account.php?id=$1 [L]
```

ACTUALZIACIÓN (YA FUNCIONA)
Quedaria asi

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %@{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %@{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

#   Reescribir la URL solicitada por el usuario
RewriteRule ^@(.*)$  /account.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres? a la página "www.twitter.com" o lo siguiente "/@Usuario."
Explícate para que puedan ayudarte.

Comment: te sugiero investigar sobre URLS amigables: https://www.emenia.es/como-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess/

Comment: Eso,. las urls amigables. Gracias :)

Comment: dale adelanta intentalo y cuando ya tengas problemas con ello edita esta pregunta para ayudarte..!! @MarkusTechESP

Comment: lo he modificado

Comment: Solo cambia la última línea por `RewriteRule ^@([^\/]+)$ /account.php?id=$1 [B,QSA]`

Comment: @MarkusTechESP te recomiendo que agregues los flags [B] y [QSA], reemplaza tu última línea por  `RewriteRule ^@(.*)$  /account.php?id=$1 [L, B, QSA]`